# Linking a FuncAnimation() with a Button in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, matplotlib-widget

I am trying to start a graph (which is it's getting data from serial port) on a button's click. I had tried the following code but was not successful. I am new to python. Please help me in guiding were I am wrong.

I am using Python 2.7 with Tkinter

Thanks in advance

```
import serial
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import figureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkFileDialog


x = []
adc_data = []


f = plt.Figure(figsize = (9,5), dpi = 100)
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

def select(self):
    self.BaudRate = self.Baud.get()
    self.COMPort = self.COM.get()

    self.ser = serial.Serial(port = self.COMPort, baudrate = self.BaudRate,bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE)
    self.ser.close()
    self.ser.open()
    self.ser.flushInput();
    self.ser.flushOutput();

def quit_(self):
    self.ser.close()


def animate_(i):
     self.ser.write(str(chr(250)))

     data = self.ser.read(1)
     data1 = self.ser.read(1)

     LSB = ord(data)
     MSB = ord(data1)

     x.append(LSB)
     adc_data.append(MSB) #adding data to list
     plt.pause(.00001)


     ax.clear()
     ax.plot(x,adc_data)


def animate_button(self):
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate_,interval=1000)



class ADC_Ref_Data(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self, '900x600+200+150')
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "ADC Reference")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Stop", state = 'disable',
                        command=lambda: quit_(self))
        self.button.place(relx = 0.97, rely = 0.95, height = 30 , width = 80, anchor = 'se')

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Select",
                        command = lambda:select(self))
        button2.place(relx = 0.97, rely = 0.016, height = 30 , width = 80, anchor = 'ne')


        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start",
                        command=lambda: animate_button(self))
        button4.place(relx = 0.03, rely = 0.95,  height = 30 , width = 80 , anchor = 'sw')




        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.48, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.8, anchor = 'center' )



app = ADC_Ref_Data()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I got success in getting my plot to start on button click. 
To get my code working I just need to add a simple line in it which is as follow:

```
def animate_button(self):
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate_,frames = 10, interval=1000)
    f.canvas.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for future travelers: There are a couple functions that are not documented that you can use to control the animation. [See this answer for an example of start, stop and pause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481541/2229945).